# How to define multi line string in a variable and refer it in same values.yaml file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a values file as shown below,

**Values.yaml:**

```
configs:
  subConfig:
    - name: abc
      mainConifg: 
        field1: 'same-name'
        multiLineString: |- 
                {{" "}}(
                {{- with .CommonLabels.Remove .GroupLabels.Names }}
                  {{- range $index, $label := .SortedPairs -}}
                    {{ if $index }}, {{ end }}
                    {{- $label.Name }}="{{ $label.Value -}}"
                  {{- end }}
                {{- end -}}
                ) 
    - name: xyz
      mainConifg: 
        field1: 'same-name'
        multiLineString: |- 
                {{" "}}(
                {{- with .CommonLabels.Remove .GroupLabels.Names }}
                  {{- range $index, $label := .SortedPairs -}}
                    {{ if $index }}, {{ end }}
                    {{- $label.Name }}="{{ $label.Value -}}"
                  {{- end }}
                {{- end -}}
                )
```

As the `mainConfig` block is repeating, I want to define it once and take reference of it to have a maintainable code. How to achieve that?

Read about [YAML anchors](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/yaml_techniques/#yaml-anchors), but not sure how to use it for multi-line string i.e., `multiLineString` field in my case.

The other reason for not using `anchoring` is, it may create subtle bugs as mentioned in the linked docs. Is there any other better way of handling this case?

Update:

The values will be utilized in `secrets.yaml` file as shown below,

**secrets.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
data:
  configfile.yaml: {{ tpl (toYaml .Values.config) . | b64enc | quote }}
```

Comment: How is this field used in your chart?  The piece you show is a configuration input to the chart; rather than trying to add scripting or unusual syntax to the configuration, can you restructure the chart – the code that consumes this configuration – to not require it to be repeated?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have update the post with details. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repeating the `mainConfig` block for each `subConfig`, you can define it separately and then reference it using an anchor & alias technique in `YAML`.
Would look something like this:

```yaml
configs:
  mainConfig: &mainConfig
    field1: 'same-name'
    multiLineString: |-
      {{" "}}(
      {{- with .CommonLabels.Remove .GroupLabels.Names }}
        {{- range $index, $label := .SortedPairs -}}
          {{ if $index }}, {{ end }}
          {{- $label.Name }}="{{ $label.Value -}}"
        {{- end }}
      {{- end -}}
      )

  subConfig:
    - name: abc
      mainConfig: *mainConfig
    - name: xyz
      mainConfig: *mainConfig
```

Comment: Thanks! The other reason for not using `anchoring` is, it may create subtle bugs as mentioned in the linked docs. Is there any other better way of handling this case?

Answer (score 0):

In your Secret object, you just pass through the extended settings from the configuration unmodified.  You can use the full power of the templating engine in the `templates/secret.yaml` file, and rearrange the configuration to not have duplicated values.

In the specific context of constructing a Secret, you'll need to base64 encode the content, so the easiest thing to do is to write a helper template to produce the content, call it, and base64 encode the result.  For most other objects you could create the content inline.

```yaml
{{- define "secret-content" -}}
...
{{ end -}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
data:
  configfile.yaml: {{ include "secret-content" . | b64enc }}
```

If you mostly wanted to preserve the structure of the configuration file, you could move what you currently have as the duplicated `mainConfig` up to a new top-level value.  For example, you could rearrange the values to look like

```yaml
mainConifg:
  field1: same-name
  multiLineString: '...'
subConfigNames:
  - abc
  - xyz
```

And then you can render this in code

```yaml
{{- define "secret-content" -}}
{{- $mainConifg := .Values.mainConifg -}}
configs:
  subConfig:
{{- range .Values.subConfigNames }}
    - name: {{ . }}
      mainConifg:
{{ $mainConifg | toYaml | indent 8 }}
{{- end }}
{{ end }}
```

The original values file you show uses Go template `{{ ... }}` syntax.  Some tools accept this as configuration settings, and I've shown this so far it will be replicated in the Secret.  The specific things you reference don't quite look like Helm objects.

But, you use `tpl` in the Secret object to render this.  If the content here is intended to be Helm templating and executed as part of constructing the Secret content, you could insert `tpl` in the same place here to render the return value of the helper function.  You also might consider moving all of the code into the `templates/secret.yaml` file, generating almost all of the file structure in helper templates and just leaving the specific values that the administrator would need to configure in the `values.yaml` file.